# Boundary of a compact connected set in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

If I have a compact connected set in $\Bbb R^2$, and I'm examining the boundary points of this set. Is it true that around every cusp/corner on the boundary, there's an open interval where the boundary is smooth? This seems intuitive to me, but I don't know if it's true.

I.e.: is it possible that the boundary is somehow badly behaved everywhere?

Comment: Like a fractal maybe? You need to be more precise about "badly behaved everywhere" andwhat "corner" is?

Comment: I think a fractal might give a counterexample, but I'm not sure if a fractal is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a function $f : [0,1]\to \mathbb R$ which is continuous but nowhere differentiable with $f\geq 0, f(0)=f(1)=0$, and take $\{(x,y) \mid x\in [0,1] \land -f(x)\leq y \leq f(x)\}$.

This is clearly connected and compact. But the boundary is not smooth at any point, as the boundary is precisely the union of the graphs of $f$ and $-f$

Comment: Which is not true, unless $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $f(x)\geq 0$.

Comment: @freakish : yes of course, let me add that

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes to my mind are fractals, in particular [the Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) and its boundary. The set indeed is compact and connected. That's what I would call an "everywhere badly behaving boundary".

---